# Reverse letters in my words without reversing the words in the sentence

Tags: java, tokenize, stringbuilder

This code should reverse my input of "123ab 445 Hello" to "ba321 544 olleh", however, I get "olleh 544 ba321" as my output. Why is this happening?

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LessNaiveEncryption {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Provide an input sentence: ");
        String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(userInput, " ", true);
        System.out.print("The output sentence is   : ");
        while (strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            strTokenizer.nextToken();
        }
        StringBuilder blob = new StringBuilder(userInput);
        blob.reverse();
        System.out.println(blob);
        System.out.print("\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and find out for yourself

Comment: Well, the `while` loop is doing nothing whatsoever, and the `StringBuilder` is used to reverse the *entire* string, so what did you expect?

Comment: Both valid points. I didn't know how to use a debugger until this morning. I will certainly implement that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that you're not doing anything with your StringTokenizer. You're iterating through the results, but not reversing them. Place the reverse inside the loop and print out the results.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Provide an input sentence: ");
    String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer strTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(userInput, " ", true);
    System.out.print("The output sentence is   : ");
    while (strTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String str = strTokenizer.nextToken();
        StringBuilder blob = new StringBuilder(str);
        System.out.print(blob.reverse());
    }

    System.out.print("\n");
 }
```

Comment: Ah I see. . . This was my first time fooling around with these concepts, so thank you for the clarification. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reversing the entire String, split it and then reverse each split:

```
String[] split = userInput.split(" ");
String result = "";
for(String s : split){
    result += new StringBuilder(s).reverse().append(" ").toString();
}
System.out.println(result);
```